# How to show sequential number in MySQL query result

Tags: mysql, select

I have some simple query:

```
SELECT foo, bar FROM table
```

i think you now whats the result looks like.

What I want to do is to show some sequential number based on how many data appear from query result. its just like `AUTO_INCREMENT`(its not mean i want to show ID).
The result what I want is like:

```
|No|   foo   |    bar   |
-------------------------
|1 |   bla   |    123   |
|2 |   boo   |    abc   |
|3 |   wow   |    xxx   |
```

How should I do to make it?

thanks in advance

Answer (score 49, accepted):

```
select @rownum:=@rownum+1 No, foo, bar from table, (SELECT @rownum:=0) r;
```

Comment: its not like mysql query, is it?

Comment: @Harry joy: i'm sorry for my limited mysql knowledge.

Comment: @bungdito: are you have some recomended tutorial for this? i really new for that query. terima kasih atas bantuannya.

Comment: http://forums.mysql.com/read.php?10,36490,36511
or
http://jimlife.wordpress.com/2008/09/09/displaying-row-number-rownum-in-mysql/

Answer (score 12):

The order gets scrambled if you are using `GROUP BY` clause in your query. The work around is putting your query inside the `FROM` clause like this.

```
SET @a:=0;
SELECT @a:=@a+1 No, output.*
FROM (
     SELECT foo, bar
     FROM table GROUP BY foo, bar
 ) output;
```

Answer (score 9):

Neither of the answers worked for me, but based on [bungdito](https://stackoverflow.com/users/672726/bungdito)'s [source](http://forums.mysql.com/read.php?10,36490,36511), I realized you can do something easier:

```
SET @a:=0;
SELECT @a:=@a+1 No, foo, bar
FROM table;
```

So, first make sure `SET @a:=0;` runs. That will set up your variable, a. Then you can increment it in the results with `@a:=@a+1`. I tested this with GROUP BY, ORDER BY, even JOINS and it worked as expected.

Comment: Nice answer! Thanks for sharing. Your answer helped me, but I think it is far more readable when the AS keyword is used. This would also help beginners, like me, who may be unaware that the AS keyword can be omitted. I just discovered this last night. If a comma is accidentally deleted or forgotten you'll get a syntax error when using AS clause, but if you don't have an AS clause it will simply alias col1 as col2 with no indication despite it not being the intended behavior. But indeed a nice shorthand for advanced users like yourself. +1 for simplicity and readability to other answers. Thanks

Comment: Does not work for me when I use `ORDER BY`. The row number seems to be assigned before the sorting happens, so the row number is not ascending in the result.

Answer (score 0):

If somebody wants to display the row number after ordering records, something like this may work

```
set @a=0; 
select @a:=@a+1 serial_number,t.* 
from ( SELECT foo, bar FROM tableORDER BY bar ) t
```

Comment: This in general does unfortunately not work, see https://mariadb.com/kb/en/why-is-order-by-in-a-from-subquery-ignored/

Answer (score 0):

I think this could be best achieved by:

```
select my_column, row_number() over (order by my_column) as No from my_table
```