# At what position is a particular record among other records?

Tags: mysql

So I have a query like this:

```
SELECT * from `news` order by `date` desc
```

And I have a particular id. Now I need to know at which position is this record. So if we have the following records:

```
id title date
1  lorem 2015-02-19
4  ipsum 2015-02-18
6  dolor 2015-02-17
7  sit   2015-02-16
```

How can I know at which position is "dolor" (id==6) when sorting by date?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to show sequential number in MySQL query result](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6055791/how-to-show-sequential-number-in-mysql-query-result)

Comment: really this question deserves an upvote?

Comment: Thanks, but it's not quite what I want. I will get a position of each row, but then I'll have to manually find this particular row anyway (in PHP for example). Thing is, I can do this without this MySql trick:)

Comment: @Strawberry - pagination. Let's say I have 100 news with 10 news per page, now when user enters a particular news there is a button "go back to list" - which should open news at the right page, so I need to know the position of this news.

Comment: I still don't get it. This is back-to-front. You wouldn't ask 'what position is id 6'. Instead you would ask 'what id is at position 3'. A simple LIMIT will tell you that - although if it was me (and depending on the size of the data set) I'd probably handle the whole pagination thing in the application code.

Comment: @Strawberry - OK, thanks, I'll handle this in PHP.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT @row_number:=@row_number+1 AS row_number,id, title, date FROM  news , (SELECT @row_number:=0) AS t order by date desc
```