# update an ordered sql table and set an incresing value

Tags: mysql, virtuemart

I use this code to order some virtuemart products how i want and the result is like the photo

```
SELECT m8jnx_virtuemart_product_categories.* ,m8jnx_virtuemart_products_el_gr.product_s_desc
FROM m8jnx_virtuemart_product_categories
INNER JOIN m8jnx_virtuemart_products_el_gr ON m8jnx_virtuemart_product_categories.virtuemart_product_id = m8jnx_virtuemart_products_el_gr.virtuemart_product_id
where `virtuemart_category_id` =272
GROUP BY `m8jnx_virtuemart_product_categories`.`virtuemart_product_id`
ORDER BY `m8jnx_virtuemart_products_el_gr`.`product_s_desc` desc
```

[image]

I want to set to the `ordering` an increasing value for this order I have do is this possible?

edit - I mean set in the first row ordering =1 in the second ordering=2, in third 3 etc -

Edit i found this sql queries in an other post but i don't know how to make work in my case that i use allready an inner join

```
UPDATE Test 
SET Number = rowNumber 
FROM Test
INNER JOIN 
(SELECT ID, row_number() OVER (ORDER BY ID DESC) as rowNumber
FROM Test) drRowNumbers ON drRowNumbers.ID = Test.ID
```

edit The question is not duplicate I want to update the 'ordering' column that already exist not display only a column with an incresing value

Comment: "i want to set to the ordering an incresing value for this odrer" - huh?

Comment: The question is somewhat unclear. Are you intending to increase the ordering field by 1 every time you run this query or are you intending for each result to have an incrementing value for ordering.

For the former you would need to store the current order number somewhere and relieve this. Alternatively you could create a procedure that automatically obtains the next order number and updates the current value stored.

Comment: I mean set in the first row ordering =1 in the second ordering=2, in third 3 etc

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to show sequential number in MySQL query result](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6055791/how-to-show-sequential-number-in-mysql-query-result)

Comment: I want to update the 'ordering' column that already exist not display only a column with an incresing value