# Trying to get correct numbering for my sorted result using MySQL but the Order By Command Screws Up

Tags: mysql

Good day to you all of you,

I am trying to build a system that can get players from taekwondo matches and award them points and then want to sort them with a number from 1st place to the last place based on the total points they have.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/x1jhJ.png)

```
'3', '35', 'Sayed Ali Hassan Saleh', 'YOUTH', 'U30Kg', '8', '4', '0', '12'
'1', '21', 'Ahmed Basem Ahmed', 'YOUTH', 'U30Kg', '8', '3', '1', '9'
'2', '22', 'Elias Abdulla Habib', 'YOUTH', 'U30Kg', '8', '2', '2', '6'
'5', '39', 'Hassan Mahmood Khalil', 'YOUTH', 'U30Kg', '8', '1', '3', '3'
'4', '37', 'Mohammed Hussain Juma Ahmed', 'YOUTH', 'U30Kg', '8', '0', '4', '0'
```

I have tried some methods from StackOverflow

[How to show sequential number in MySQL query result](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6055791/how-to-show-sequential-number-in-mysql-query-result)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/utEDX.png)

but I never got the result I wanted pls help

```
select
    @row := @row + 1 as row,
    person.id as PID,
    concat(person.fname, ' ', person.mname, ' ', person.lname) as NAME,
    person.category as CATEGORY,
    person.weight_class as WEIGHTCLASS,
    (select count(*) from event_matches where blue_fighter = person.id or red_fighter = person.id) as MATCHES,
    (select count(*) from event_matches where (blue_fighter = person.id or red_fighter = person.id) and winner = person.id) as WIN,
    (select count(*) from event_matches where (blue_fighter = person.id or red_fighter = person.id) and winner != person.id and winner != 0) as LOSS,
    (select count(*) from event_matches where (blue_fighter = person.id or red_fighter = person.id) and winner = person.id) * 3 as POINTS
from 
    person, (SELECT @row := 0) r
where
    person.category = 'YOUTH'
    and
    person.weight_class = 'U30Kg'
    and
    person.gender = 'MALE'

order by
    POINTS
    desc
```

```
'1', '35', 'Sayed Ali Hassan Saleh', 'YOUTH', 'U30Kg', '8', '4', '0', '12'
'2', '21', 'Ahmed Basem Ahmed', 'YOUTH', 'U30Kg', '8', '3', '1', '9'
'3', '22', 'Elias Abdulla Habib', 'YOUTH', 'U30Kg', '8', '2', '2', '6'
'4', '39', 'Hassan Mahmood Khalil', 'YOUTH', 'U30Kg', '8', '1', '3', '3'
'5', '37', 'Mohammed Hussain Juma Ahmed', 'YOUTH', 'U30Kg', '8', '0', '4', '0'
```

Answer (score 0):

The Following Methode Solved The Problem, but I had to create a view, is there any other alternative?

```
create view 
    event_event_youth_male_u30kgyouth_male_u30kg as

select
    person.id as PID,
    concat(person.fname, ' ', person.mname, ' ', person.lname) as NAME,
    person.category as CATEGORY,
    person.weight_class as WEIGHTCLASS,
    (select count(*) from event_matches where blue_fighter = person.id or red_fighter = person.id) as MATCHES,
    (select count(*) from event_matches where (blue_fighter = person.id or red_fighter = person.id) and winner = person.id) as WIN,
    (select count(*) from event_matches where (blue_fighter = person.id or red_fighter = person.id) and winner != person.id and winner != 0) as LOSS,
    (select count(*) from event_matches where (blue_fighter = person.id or red_fighter = person.id) and winner = person.id) * 3 as POINTS

from 
    person

where
    person.category = 'YOUTH'
    and
    person.weight_class = 'U30Kg'
    and
    person.gender = 'MALE'

order by
    POINTS
    desc;

SET @a:=0;
SELECT @a:=@a+1 No, event_youth_male_u30kg.* FROM test.event_youth_male_u30kg;
```